# Cascading Deletions with Triggers --Error Code: 1442. Can't update table in stored function/trigger because

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete, cascade

process:

I want to use a trigger to achieve cascade deletion, I created two tables, one for teachers and one for departments (see figure, only the primary key is set in both tables, both are the first column), I created a del trigger to achieve cascade deletion (after deleting the data in the dept table, the related rows in the teacher table are also deleted), after successful creation and issuing the delete command, the error message in the red box appears.[Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'dept' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
]

Here are the two table I create:

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
dno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
dname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
pnumber int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (dno))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE teacher(
tnum varchar(20) NOT NULL,
tname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
tsex varchar(20) NOT NULL,
title varchar(20) NOT NULL,
wage int NOT NULL,
dno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tnum)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here are the trigger I create:

```
create trigger del
after delete on dept
for each row
delete fromteacher where dno=old.dno;
```

Here is the query:

```
delete from dept where dno='9';
```

Then appear the error:

```
action:delete from dept where dno='9' 
response:Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'dept' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. 0.0019 sec
```

Checked the online forum for the cause of the error is not to delete the same table and other operations to avoid recursive loops, but I am to two different tables to achieve the delete operation.

There are many examples of this kind on the Internet, so I don't understand why it's reported as an error here, and it's the first time I asked a question on this forum, so I'm not sure about the format of the question, so please forgive me if I'm not clear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uleJ9.png)

Comment: Pls share the code with us - my guess is you are trying to modify the table the trigger is declared on, which is a no go.

Comment: Why don´t you use foreign keys to do it??

Comment: @Shadow sorry, i have shared

Comment: @nacho just homework